# Shell script for "intelligent" copying

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm working on a shell script. To the backgroud: I recorded a lot of songs from the radio with my Mac. Each song is a `*.eyetv` "file" on my mac. Actually these "files" are just folders, containing a `.mpg` file with a cryptical filename like `00000000144ad5e9.mpg` and some metadata.

The recordings are organized in a few folders, each containing like 20 recordings (an audio CD). All these folders are on a NAS.

I'm trying to write a script, which creates folders on my mac and then copies the mpgs into them *renaming* them to the name of their parent directory.

Directory structure on the NAS for the example song "`Set fire to the Rain`": `/music/recordings1/Set Fire to the Rain - ADELE.eyetv/00000000144ad5e9.mpg` (and some metadata for EyeTv)

Desired structure on my hard disc after copying: /`home/me/music/recordings1/Set fire to the Rain.mpg`

My (not working) code so far:

```
dirname=$(basename `pwd | tr ' ' '_'`.eyetv)
mkdir ~/Musik/$dirname
find . -name '*.eytv' | xargs -0 -i cd {} | find . -name ????????????????.mpg -print0 | xargs -0 -i cp -v {} ~/Musik/$dirname/$(basename `pwd | tr ' ' '_'`.mpg)
```

Greetings ant thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! NOT! Mac! see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29

Comment: Don't worry, I'm in the right place ;) I want to do this with my Ubuntu computer. Maybe I should have added that... Most players on Ubuntu play the mpgs directley. On my Mac I would have to convert them, which reduces the quality significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mcp`:

```
mcp -v '/music/recordings1/* - *.eyetv/*.mpg' '/home/me/music/recordings1/#1.mpg'
```

`mcp` is included in [`mmv`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mmv/) package. By default, `mmv` is not installed in Ubuntu, but you can install it from terminal using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mmv
```

See [`man mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/mln.1.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed. I have some whitespace issues left, but I think, I can make it from here.